# Currency to number conversion rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Rails 4.1
   Ruby 2.0
   Windows 8.1

I found the number_to_currency helper, but no currency_to_number. I am trying to convert something like $8,000 into a decimal. Are there any Rails helpers for that? Any ideas?

## Comment:

I have been using this:

```
number.to_s.gsub(/[^\d\.]/, '').to_f
```

Which eliminates everything with the exception of numerals and the decimal point and also handles the accidental integer. I was wondering if I'm missing some sort of currency_to_number helper. It looks like I am not. I will accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jorge's answer is good, but I think you'll need to know how the currency is entered. This will require whitelisting more than black listing.

```
def currency_to_number currency
 currency.to_s.gsub(/[$,]/,'').to_f
end
```

Comment: This is the most efficient approach for sure.

Comment: I guess this deals better with non-US possibilities

Comment: I believe in many countries a comma is used as a decimal separator. Running this code on a value such as "23,00 $" (meaning 23 dollars) converts it to 2300 instead of 23.

Answer (score 1):

The number_to_currency formats a number. If you are trying to convert something like $8.000 into a number you might want to create a new method to parse the string into a number. something like:

```
result = "$8.000".gsub(/[^\d]/, '').to_f
```

For an improved conversion of something like:

"$8.000,00"

You are going to need a better regexp.

Comment: Don't use this. Converts `"$80.00"` to `8000.0`, and `"-$1000"` to `1000.0`

Comment: Please don't take it personally. These answers are not "partially correct", they are *dangerously broken* and it's important for people to know the dangers. We're talking about currency here. One day someone is going to cut and paste this code into their application and end up issuing a $8000 refund instead of a $80 invoice.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this in IRB you will want to put this in some sort of method for use with Rails though.

```
price = "$8,000.90"
price.match(/(\d.+)/)[1].gsub(',','').to_f

#=> 8000.9
```

Comment: This is a better approach, especially dealing with US numbers

Comment: Don't use this. Fails on `$8`. Also fails for European formatted numbers and converts negative numbers to positive numbers

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in method, but a method like this would do the trick

```
def currency_to_number(currency_value)
  (currency_value.is_a? String) ? currency_value.scan(/[.0-9]/).join.to_d : currency_value
end
```

This method returns a Decimal if a String is passed, if you want a float, use ".to_f" instead.

Comment: Don't use this. It's flips negative values to positive, (and doesn't work for European formatted numbers).